# Use handsontable with an existing table

Tags: jquery, handsontable

do you know if I can use hansontable jquery plugin with a table which is already exists ?

Because in the documentation, I saw that we can create a table with handsontable like that :

```
var data = [
  ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var $container = $("#example1");
$container.handsontable({
  data: data
});
```

But I wish to do something like that :

```
$("#monTableau").handsontable();
```

in order to give handsontable's feature to my table

Do you have an idea please ?

Comment: you could always get the values from your table, delete the table and create an handsontable

Answer (score 1):

workaround:

```
    var data = [];
$('#monTableau tr').each(function(index,el){
    var rowData = [];
    $(el).children().each(function(index,el){
        rowData.push($(el).html()); //or use text() if u prefer
    });
    data.push(rowData);
});
el = $('#monTableau').after('<div class="handsontable"></div>').next();
$('#monTableau').remove();
el.handsontable({ data : date });
```

or extend the library yourself to make it possible.

Comment: Thanks. I must replace "index" and "el" ? Or it exists already ?

Comment: those will be filled by jquery for each function. check documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/